# Python axis indicator issue in numpy.delete() and numpy.sum()

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, axis

In

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

```
>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=0)
array([0, 6])
>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)
array([1, 5])
```

So it looks like axis=0 is y-axis, i.e., going vertically. However, in

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> np.delete(arr, 1, 0)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

axis=0 indicates x-axis, i.e., going horizontally.

Why axis behaviors so different in two methods?

Comment: They are consistent - your delete command removed *everything* in the 2nd (index 1) row, rows being the vertical dimension (axis=0).

Comment: Hi Ajean, I did not get your reply. You said row is in the vertical dimension, then why delete() remove the horizontal slice?

Comment: Think about it: you want to delete the first row, second row, third row?  That's your 1, 2, 3, etc. moving down.  But when you remove the row, all the horizontal elements are what is removed.  If a vertical slice were removed, you'd be removing a column.

Comment: Hi, Ajean, thanks for the further comment, I think I have figured out:)